# I want to add excel button in my data table for excel export

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, datatable

I am trying to add excel button by

```
 buttons: [
        'excel'
    ]
```

But it is not working

My code:

```
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-9">
         <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
               <h4 class="mt-0 mb-3 header-title">Subscribers</h4>
               <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-12">
                     <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table id="all_sub" class="table">
                           <thead class="thead-light">
                              <tr>
                                 <th>Subscriber Name</th>
                                 <th>Course Name</th>
                              </tr>
                           </thead>
                         <tbody>
                         <?php foreach($allsubscriber as $allsub):?>
                           <tr>
                           <td><?php echo $allsub->user_firstname;?></td>
                           <td><?php echo $allsub->course_title;?></td>
                         </tr>
                       <?php endforeach; ?>              
                        </tbody>
                        </table>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
<script>
  $(document).ready( function () {
    $('#all_sub').DataTable();
    buttons: [
        'excel'
    ]
});
</script>
```

In the above code, I am trying to add excel but it not working.
I do not know where I am wrong in my code.

Comment: Have you add datatable js libraries ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#all_sub').DataTable( {
    dom: 'lBfrtip',
    buttons: [ 
        'excelHtml5', 
    ]
} );
} );
```

And load the below datatable libraries

```
https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css
https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css

https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js
https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js
https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/pdfmake.min.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/vfs_fonts.js
https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/buttons.html5.min.js
```

Comment: it adds excel button but hides the page filter

Comment: No , it will not hides the page filter. check here https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/simple.html

Comment: What do you mean by page filter ? Is this datatable search filter or your custom filter?

Comment: Show entries dropdown  is hide

Comment: I have updated my answer . You just lack the l flag in dom. l for "length changing input control". `dom: 'lBfrtip'`

Answer (score 3):

> **Note:-** Please note - this property requires the [Buttons](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons) extension for
>   DataTables.

CSS

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">
```

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
```

HTML

```
<table id="all_sub" class="table">
    <thead class="thead-light">
        <tr>
            <th>Subscriber Name</th>
            <th>Course Name</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach($allsubscriber as $allsub):?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $allsub->user_firstname;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $allsub->course_title;?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>              
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JQuery Script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
        ]
    } );
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

you are putting buttons after calling `DataTable()` but it should be passed as parameter.

see below code

```
$('#all_sub').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'excel'
        ]
    } );
```

Also, you need to include below required JS (jQuery version may vary as per datable plugin used)

```
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js
https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js
https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js
https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/buttons.html5.min.js
```

See [Datable](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/simple.html) for more information